# Issue adding new deployment cluster using ArgoCD CLI

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am trying to add a new deployment cluster to `ArgoCD` using `ArgoCD CLI`. I have combined both the `kube-config` files and set `current-context` pointing to the deployment cluster name.

Using `argocd login <node-ip>:<node-port>`, I successfully logged into the server.

When I execute the command `argocd cluster add <deployment-cluster-name>`, it gives the below error:

```
INFO[0000] ServiceAccount "argocd-manager" already exists in namespace "kube-system"
INFO[0000] ClusterRole "argocd-manager-role" updated
INFO[0000] ClusterRoleBinding "argocd-manager-role-binding" updated
FATA[0030] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get "https://<deployment-cluster-name>:6443/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<deployment-cluster-name>` is a cluster name what you want to add, you need replace the `<deployment-cluster-name>` to your cluster name